# Shouldn't the OP of a question or answer be able to see the vote counts for it?

Tags: feature-request, vote-count, rep-requirement, original-poster

The OP of a post should be able to see the +1's and -1's of the post so that they can see if it is an overall accepted or 'hated' post, and what to do to fix it, even if they don't have 1000+ reputation.

Comment: How would seeing the split give the OP an idea of "what to do to fix it"?

Comment: Then they could ask the downvoter why they downvoted. Otherwise, it might go unnoticed.

Comment: @aj8uppal - How would they do that? Given that you can't see who voted (up or down).

Comment: They could comment as such: "Downvoter, why the downvote?", and see the response.

Comment: ... but they could already do that given that downvotes appear on their profiles and affect their reputation.

Answer (score 3):

While this is a reasonable request, at this point they can go to their reputation summary and see the total of the votes and reputation.  And of course, they're getting notification of the upvotes as they go.

Answer (score 1):

The overall of votes is shown to the user: if the score is positive then his post is good otherwise it needs improvement.

I don't think that viewing the vote count is important at all: sometimes a post get a downvote for no reason, if it is good it will probably have a positive score,  so viewing that -1 is not important at all.

If you still think this is necessary to you, there is a workaround: ["View Vote totals" without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)

I have it but I rarely use it.